# Connect with RMAN to database by ip address

Tags: database, oracle, rman

After `rman target /` I am connected to my local database, however I would like to connect to database to which I have credentials - ip, port, username, password (in general to which I can connect via SQLDeveloper). Is it possible through RMAN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't shown in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/bradv/starting-interacting-with-rman-client.html#GUID-241D7D37-D905-4E52-99B6-3FD57AE1717B), but you can use 'easy connect' syntax:

```
rman target user@hostname:port/servicename
```

or if you don't want to be prompted for the password (less secure!):

```
rman target user/password@hostname:port/servicename
```

Answer (score 1):

To use rman on a 'remote' server, you need to have oracle client installed (not the instant one, the full one). And then you can configure an entry in the tnsnames.ora file to point to which db you want. You can do, the same if you have a full db install on your system, just add an alias to the remote db.